# Is it OK to ask a question about Android administration on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

Normally Android questions on Stack Overflow are programming questions. Is it OK to ask an administration question?

Comment: Hello Zak. What do you mean by "administration question"?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Android Enthusiasts FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq) to see if your question would fit there?

Comment: @Alenanno to cut the story short, I forgot my lock pattern on my Jelly Bean device, and both wifi and 3G data connections are off. I want to find out if there is a way to root my device (Galaxy Nexus) while it is locked so I can install ClockWorkMod recovery and use ADB to pull the data from it before I hard reset the phone. Android Enthusiasts looks like the right place to ask this question as pointed out by Al Everett and Tim Post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Android question is about programming, ask it on Stack Overflow. If it's about simply using a device (or fixing, tinkering, or otherwise not programming) you should take a look at [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/), a Stack Exchange site for Android users.

It's not uncommon for people interested in Android to have accounts on both sites.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer this question without knowing what you mean by an "administration question," but my hunch is -- probably not.

Overall, SO is for specific programming questions that can be answered.  While your question sounds like it would fit most of those criteria, it doesn't sound like a direct programming question.

Questions about using the tools programmers commonly use to do their jobs can also be on-topic, but questions like these also tend to fall in to a grey area fairly frequently.  Therefore, when you mention an administration question, I wonder if it would fall in to this category.  Again, without knowing the question it is hard to say, but my experience is that by and large admin questions are almost always off-topic at SO.  Evidence of this is the existence of other SE sites where such a question would be *directly* on-topic for certian platforms, such as askubuntu.

Long story short, I would say it's probably not on-topic, but it really depends on the actual question.